# What happened to the scratches on Cap's shield?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Captain Ameria's shield got scratched by Black Panther in *Captain America: Civil War*. These were not scratches in the paint rather deep gouges made by Black Panther's vibranium claws. This being the case, why were these marks gone when Tony gave the shield back in *Endgame*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If memory serves, Cap doesn't get his iconic shield back until Tony gives it back to him in *Avengers: Engame*.   At this point around seven years have passed and we can assume that it's been repaired by most-likely Tony, or posibly the Wakandans.

Comment: I was just watching "Captain America: The First Avenger" the other night. His shield clearly got scratched/dinged up a bit during battles, so it obviously needs to be repaired/touched up periodically

Comment: @RemyLebeau I addressed that in the question. Those scratches were just in the paint not the shield